# Unexpected Right Shift Operator behavior

Tags: javascript, arithmetic-expressions

Please look at the following Node.js REPL output:

```
> n=10
10
> console.log(n.toString(2)); //ok ?
1010
undefined
> m=n>>1 
5
> console.log(m.toString(2)); //cool :)
101
```

This is working as expected. Now look at this:

```
> n=Number.MAX_VALUE
1.7976931348623157e+308
> m=n>>1
0
> n.toString(16) // to read easier
'fffffffffffff800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
> m.toString(16) // to read easier
'0'
```

What just happened here? Shouldn't me right shifting

`fffffffffffff800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

by 1 digit give me

`7ffffffffffffc00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

How did I get a zero instead?

Also, I noticed that it is not just V8/Node issue. I get the same result in Firebug.

Comment: I think you want [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

Comment: @HunterMcMillen actually, no, since that range is 53 bits, but the bit operations only work on 32 bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript when you compute `x >> y`, `x` is converted into a signed 32-bit integer. Then it is shifted right by `y` places.

Your value 0xfffffffffffff800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 is converted into 0x00000000 because those are the lowest 32 bits. Right shifting this gives zero.

Comment: ah! that makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript's bit-level operations only work on 32-bit signed values (or unsigned in the case of the zero-extending `>>>` operator).  Anything above those 32 bits is set to zero before the bit operation takes place.